# Transact SQL CONTAINS not returning match for identical strings with a wildcard

Tags: sql-server

I'm encountering an issue on SQL Server 2008r2 where use of the CONTAINS function is not returning a match for completely identical strings. I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something about CONTAINS.

I've set up the following test case to replicate it.

```
CREATE TABLE texttest
(
    loldex INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,        
    testcolumn NVARCHAR(255)
)

GO

INSERT INTO texttest
VALUES('2ND ACADEMY OF NATURAL SCIENCES')

GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_loldex ON [texttest](loldex);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [texttest]([testcolumn])
KEY INDEX ui_loldex

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;

GO
```

Then I run the following query:

```
SELECT [testcolumn]
FROM [texttest]
WHERE CONTAINS(testcolumn, '"2ND ACADEMY OF NATURAL SCIENCES*"')
```

And it returns nothing.

However, if I run:

```
SELECT [testcolumn]
FROM [texttest]
WHERE CONTAINS(testcolumn, '"2ND ACADEMY*"')
```

It returns the row.

If I use any more of the characters in the string after the Y with the wildcard, I get nothing.

If I remove the wildcard, I get the row from the identical string. However, I've tried the wildcard with other strings and it's worked fine. From what I understand, the wildcard stands for 0 or more additional characters, so I don't understand why it doesn't work in this case.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: It should as you expect find it but perhaps there is actually a double space after the Y in ACADEMY. Copy the value from your database into notepad and verify that you only have a single space. Actually check to make sure that you have a single space between each of the words.

Comment: I've checked this. I've in fact run the search by cutting and pasting the text directly from the table back into the search and it still fails.

Comment: Have you tried using a `%` instead of `*`? considering the fact CONTAINS is a fuzzy match method, why do you need a wildcard anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `of` is noise word and it will not select the results if you search by `stopwords`. You can see all stop words :

```
select ssw.stopword, slg.name
  from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords ssw
  join sys.fulltext_languages slg on slg.lcid = ssw.language_id
where slg.name = 'English'
```

You can turn it off for your table:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [texttest] SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

You can manage `stoplists` and `stopwords`:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551(v=sql.110).aspx

For example:

```
stopword    name
must        English
my          English
never       English
no          English
now         English
of          English
on          English
only        English
or          English
other       English
our         English
out         English
over        English
re          English
```

Comment: Just curious, if I ignore the stop word - `of`, and search for `WHERE CONTAINS(testcolumn, '"2ND ACADEMY*NATURAL SCIENCES"')` this does not work still.

Comment: @PaulFrancis, there is no such term. There is prefix term but no postfix term. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx for details

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I am new to (MS)SQL. Appreciate that.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot. I thought the purpose of stopwords was so that trivial connectors such as "of" and "and" in natural language would not significantly affect the outcome of a search. Why then, would they prevent two identical phrases from matching?

Comment: @CodingUnderDuress, To prevent a full-text index from becoming bloated, SQL Server has a mechanism that discards commonly occurring strings that do not help the search. These discarded strings are called stopwords. During index creation, the Full-Text Engine omits stopwords from the full-text index. This means that full-text queries will not search on stopwords.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms142551.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use **`freetext`** function to search for whole sentence in your case:

```
SELECT [testcolumn]
FROM [texttest]
WHERE freetext(testcolumn,'"2ND ACADEMY OF NATURAL SCIENCES*"')
```

Output:

```
testcolumn
2ND ACADEMY OF NATURAL SCIENCES
```